# Where does time comes from?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

In the context of particle physics, does time flow for a particle that is isolated and has no subsystems?

Comment: That's not the same question. Mine has the consequence that if true, an isolated particle without subsystems doesn't experience time. It can move in space, but will essentially remain transparent to any other particles. Or conversely, for a particle to interact with another particle, it must have a substructure.